# .htaccess Redirect weird blog address to new directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently using this format for my 301 Redirects in my .htaccess file on the new site I am building:

```
RewriteRule ^Default.asp$ http://www.example.com/index.php [R=301]
```

I need a redirect that essentially redirects `http://www.example.com/blog/index.php/path-to-the-post/` to `http://www.example.com/blog/path-to-the-post/`.

I need to remove the `index.php` in the first URL while keeping the actual path to the post the same. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, here's the answer that worked for me:

In the `.htaccess` file of the Blog,

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `RewriteRule ^blog/index.php/(.+)$ blog/$1 [R=301]`

Comment: When I do so, I get `No input file specified` in the browser.

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /blog` before RewriteRule and try `RewriteRule index.php/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I tried `RewriteBase /blog RewriteRule index.php/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]` but got an internal server error.

Comment: Have you tried directly with redirect ? `RedirectMatch 301 index.php/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1` and are you sure http://www.example.com/blog/something is working ?